# Memory used value in pytorch is different

Tags: pytorch, memory-leaks, gpu

I have a question in the process of learning using pytorch.

referece: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html

```py
current_memory = torch.cuda.memory_allocated(device=device)     # return current GPU memory

total_free_memory = torch.cuda.mem_get_info(device=device)      # returns the total, unused GPU memory
total = mem_get_info[1] 
unused = mem_get_info[0] 
used_memory = total - unused
```

In my code,

- `total` : 11.77GB
- `used_memory`: 4.63GB
- `current_memory`: 3.1GB

I wonder the **`used_memory - current_memory`** is a leak memory.

why are the values `used_memory` and `current_memory` have different??

Thanks for any help.